# Not able to do CI get_instance() in pthreads

Tags: php, codeigniter, pthreads

I am working on CI and Try To Use Pthreads and i have a function in controller which will calls the threads and from the threads i have instanciated an object of an library using new rather than $this->load->library as my thread extends Thread Class so it doesnot allowed me to do load->library so i instantiated the class using new 
Here are my **Controller**:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
include_once APPPATH.'/libraries/feedstart_class.php';
include_once APPPATH.'/libraries/test/thread.php';

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('event_library');
            $this->load->model('global_model');
        }
        public function testThreadCommandLine() {
            $mythreads = array();
            $ci_obj = & get_instance();
            for($i = 0;$i<5;$i++) {
                $mythreads[$i] =  new MyThread();
                $mythreads[$i]->setIndex($i);
                $mythreads[$i]->setCI($ci_obj);
                $mythreads[$i]->start();
            }`enter code here`
        }
    }
```

Here is my **Thread Class**

```
include_once APPPATH.'/libraries/common_event_library.php';
    Class MyThread extends Thread
    {
        private $_index;
        private $_CI;
        public function __construct() {

        }
        public function setIndex($index) {
            $this->_index = $index;
        }
        public function setCI($ci_obj) {
            $this->_CI = $ci_obj;
        }
        public function getIndex() {
            return $this->_index;
        }
        public function run() {
            sleep(rand(0,10));
            echo "The index of the object is ".$this->_index;
            $common_event_library =  new Common_event_library($this->_CI);
            $common_event_library->display();//gets all sports categories from our system
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Here is my **library**

```
Class Common_event_library {
    private $_CI;
    public function __construct($ci_instance) {
        $this->_CI = $ci_instance;
    }
    public function display() {
        $this->_CI->db->select("*");
        $this->_CI->db->from("sports_cateogry");
        $result = $this->_CI->db->get()->result();
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

When i run the testThreadCommandLine from both browser and command line it says Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\libraries\common_event_library.php

Comment: when i did var_dump($this->_CI) i get null

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor of Common_event_library should be

```
function __construct($ci_instance){
    $this->_CI = $ci_instance;
}
```

You are passing it in here, but nothing is receiving it.:

> $common_event_library =  new Common_event_library($this->_CI);

Comment: yeah i tried it but when i run in command it says CLI has stopped working and from browser it says the page is not available you can check now i have also edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Constructor in Common_event_library() must include
    parent::__construct();